# Edge weights in directed graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Apologies for what seems like a silly question. I'm sure I am missing something obvious, but this is driving me a bit crazy.

Does EdgeWeight work differently in Directed vs. Undirected graphs?

If I have a weighted undirected graph, I can assign and then extract the list of edge weights, or individual weights, as follows:

```
G = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4}, 
   EdgeWeight -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}];
PropertyValue[G, EdgeWeight]
PropertyValue[{G, 2 <-> 3}, EdgeWeight]
```

And I get the expected output

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
2
```

However, if I try the same with a directed graph:

```
H = DirectedGraph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 2}, 
   EdgeWeight -> {6, 7, 8, 9}];
PropertyValue[H, EdgeWeight]
PropertyValue[{H, 1 -> 2}, EdgeWeight]
```

I get the following nonsense

```
Automatic
$Failed
```

As I said, I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I'm not sure what. Can anyone help?

Comment: cannot test right now, but do you get the same error if you use `\[DirectedEdge]` instead of `->`?

Comment: works fine as is  in version 12 (Wolfram Cloud).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yes, I get the same error using DirectedEdge instead of ->. Thanks for considering my question, both you and kglr.

Comment: If it matters, I am using Mathematica 11.1.1.0 on Windows.

Comment: For the record, I get the same error in 10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

Comment: this looks like an issue that is fixed in version 12 (we get the same error in v9 / windows 10).

Comment: as a work-around try if  `H = DirectedGraph[Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 2}, EdgeWeight -> {6, 7, 8, 9}]]`  works.

Comment: @kglr Amazingly, yes this seems to fix it. Thanks! If you write your last comment as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Don't use `DirectedGraph`. Use `Graph`. `Graph` is a constructor for the graph data structure, either directed or undirected. `DirectedGraph` converts undirected graphs to directed ones, an entirely different use. IMO there's no bug here, just a misuse of `DirectedGraph`.

Comment: Furthermore, `DirectedGraph` discarded all properties (including edge weights) up to M11.3. Since M12.0, many graph functions, including `DirectedGraph`, preserve properties. Why this major wasn't documented by Wolfram is beyond me ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no bug here, just a misuse of `DirectedGraph`.

You are trying to use `DirectedGraph` as a constructor. This is incorrect. As written in the documentation, the purpose of [`DirectedGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectedGraph.html) is to convert an undirected graph to a directed one, not to construct a graph.

To construct a graph from an edge list, use `Graph`.

Why does `DirectedGraph` *appear* to work as a constructor at first glance then? That's because since M10.4 most graph processing functions accept an edge list instead of a `Graph` expression.

Why do edge weights go missing? Because up to M11.3, almost all graph processing functions discard properties, including edge weights. What very likely happens is that first the edge list is converted to a `Graph` expression internally (as in all other cases when a graph function gets an edge list and not a `Graph` as input). Then `DirectedGraph` is applied to this `Graph` expression, resulting in all weights getting discarded.

Since M12.0, most graph processing functions finally preserve properties. Unfortunately, the only indication that this was changed is a short note on the "What's New in 12" page.

---

In either version, you should not use `DirectedGraph` as a constructor. Always use `Graph` for this purpose.

Comment: Okay, I think I see. Thank you for the clear explanation.